# Fixing a shader that behaves differently (3.2a =>3.2b)

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, caustics

Basically, I've constructed a shader that I'm very happy with using `blender-3.2.0-alpha+master.295d5c6ef5b9-windows.amd64-release`.

When I tried to import it into my project that's coming together (and I decided to use a more stable version as soon as it was available - `blender-3.2.0-beta+v32.84e55e3dc251-windows.amd64-release`), I've noticed a distinct difference in behavior, which I attribute to the Mix Shader node's `Fac` input somehow clamping/remapping its input.

Granted, its behavior in 3.2a and earlier **was** a lucky buggy accident, but it looks so awesome in my opinion. And now I need to either recreate it in 3.2b or port everything (including downgrading the addons I use) back to 3.2a (and face who knows how many other complications).

Trouble is, I have no idea what's happening to the shader under the hood.

Here are both of them back to back. Same file, on the left - the magic of 3.2a; on the right - the bleak imitation of 3.2b!
[image]

And here's the full shader tree, made by following this [Glass 2.0 guide by CG Vertex](https://youtu.be/-hVo_NuzAcU)
[image]

Tried stacking "add shader" on top of each other, but I haven't figured it out yet, and I'm not very sure how can I utilize MixRGB.

I have a hunch that multiplication node is somehow pushing the RGB values past 1, which makes the surface emissive. **But I can't figure out how to replicate the look and not lose other components of it** - transmissiveness and caustics (not to mention that I'd like to learn from this interesting experience).

Currently trying to find something relevant in the changelogs, but nothing about "factor clamping mix shader" so far..

Also, `blender-3.1.0-stable+v31.c77597cd0e15-windows.amd64-release` is just as wonderful!
[image]

**UPD**: `blender-3.2.0-candidate+v32.34f94a02f370-windows.amd64-release` does not partake in the awesome colorfulness either (it's a current release candidate at the time of writing this).

**UPD2**: The future looks bleak as even `blender-3.3.0-alpha+master.8589f60546b3-windows.amd64-release` does not respect the multiplication node.

**UPD3**: The 3.1st/3.2a behavior is considered buggy, and it was "fixed" - a hardcoded factor clamp on the mix node, most likely.

You can see my [post on devs' forum about this issue](https://developer.blender.org/T98641) and the response I got for more info.

I'm still looking for workaround though.

**UPD4**: `blender-3.2.0-candidate+v32.34f94a02f370-windows.amd64-release`
[image]
[image]

For some reason Glass BDSF still works with Shader to RGB (even though the docs say that anything with refraction wouldn't work, even something as simple as a Transparent BSDF doesn't!)

So I converted its result to an RGB, boosted and played around with it. Still needs some tweaking, will probably add random white flares and stuff.
The resulting node tree:
[image]